# Launch activity when google.com opened in browser

Tags: java, android, android-intent, browser

I am trying to launch my activity when google.com is navigated to in the browser, but it is not working. Here is my manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http" 
                    android:host="google.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: John, pls edit in your intent launch code - how are you trapping the url? Are you using webkit, etc ?

Comment: Are you clicking a link or typing in the address bar? Is it google.com or www.google.com?

Comment: I am typing google.com into the address bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intent-filter not working from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799065/intent-filter-not-working-from-browser)

Comment: Doesn't work using a link either.