# redirect user from browser to android app

Tags: android

I have a simple webiste like this
`<a href="https://golderer.000webhostapp.com/">click</a>`

I want to redirect the user from android chrome to my app

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
     android:scheme="https"
    android:host="golderer.000webhostapp.com" />
    </intent-filter>
```

my app link: https://golderer.000webhostapp.com
and it is verified on app links assistant.
success your app is associated with the selected domains

it is working when links in email / note app ,
however, it does not redirect the user form the browser instead it opens the link in chrome

can I redirect the user from my website to the app ?
should I use fireabse dynamic links?

Comment: Could it be that you set in the Device settings before that links should always be opened within the Chrome browser? In Android Settings, if you go to the Chrome app info page, there might be some option asking "whether to open links in browser, or always ask". You also might check the app info of your app. Just to make sure that the problem does not come from a setting misconfiguration.

Comment: no default set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make sure that you add .well-known/assetlinks.json to your website

from this link check if your the file is reachble
https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Answer (score 0):

For Android 12 or above, read : https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#manual-verification

You might want to add the link to Verified links using the steps (Android 12):

1. Goto phone settings,
2. Search "Link"
3. Choose **Opening links**
4. locate your app
5. Click add link
6. Add your link that you need

Now try opening that link in a browser.