# Android App Links. How to process a link containing "#"

Tags: android

I have the following link that my application needs to process: https://example.com/#page1.
I specified the following in the application manifest, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:path="/#page1"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? How do you handle an intent in your Activity?

Comment: @DmitriChernysh The application does not recognize this link and does not open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android App Links do not support links with anchors

Answer (score 0):

If you do not own the site, you have to set up a redirect in the app settings, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73743424/15749574

Comment: and also, I don't think the `#` will be a problem